# How do i save one subscription pub/sub message to three different big query tables in apache beam in python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pipeline, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created three process and want to save data but this is not working for me.

Below is my custom pardo:

```
subscription = "pub/sub/writeToBigquery"
dataset_table1="A"
dataset_table2="B"
dataset_table3="c"
Schema1="et:timestamp,name:string,Day:integer"
schema2="et:timestamp,Place:string,Month:integer"
schema3="et:timestamp,Location:string,Year:integer"

    class CustomParsing(beam.DoFn):

        def process1(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
            parsed = dict()
            parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
            parsed["et"] = parsed.et,
            parsed["name"] = parsed.name
            parsed["Day"] = parsed.day
            yield parsed

       def process2(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
            parsed = dict()
            parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
            parsed["et"] = parsed.et,
            parsed["name"] = parsed.place
            parsed["Day"] = parsed.month
            yield parsed

      def process3(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
            parsed = dict()
            parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
            parsed["et"] = parsed.et,
            parsed["name"] = parsed.location
            parsed["Day"] = parsed.year
            yield parsed
```

How to write this in big query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with 3 sinks, example :

```py
def process1(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
    parsed = dict()
    parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
    parsed["et"] = parsed.et,
    parsed["name"] = parsed.name
    parsed["Day"] = parsed.day
    yield parsed

def process2(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
    parsed = dict()
    parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
    parsed["et"] = parsed.et,
    parsed["name"] = parsed.place
    parsed["Day"] = parsed.month
    yield parsed

def process3(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
    parsed = dict()
    parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
    parsed["et"] = parsed.et,
    parsed["name"] = parsed.location
    parsed["Day"] = parsed.year
    yield parsed

def main() -> None:
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    your_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(YourOptions)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        result_pcollection_pub_sub = p | 'Read from pub sub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription='input_subscription')

        (result_pcollection_pub_sub |
         'Map BQ table 1' >> beam.Map(process1) |
         'Write to BQ table 1' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    project='project_id',
                    dataset='dataset',
                    table='table1',
                    method='STREAMING_INSERTS',
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER))

        (result_pcollection_pub_sub |
         'Map BQ table 2' >> beam.Map(process2) |
         'Write to BQ table 2' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    project='project_id',
                    dataset='dataset',
                    table='table2',
                    method='STREAMING_INSERTS',
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER))

        (result_pcollection_pub_sub |
         'Map BQ table 3' >> beam.Map(process3) |
         'Write to BQ table 3' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    project='project_id',
                    dataset='dataset',
                    table='table3',
                    method='STREAMING_INSERTS',
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- The first `PCollection` is the result of input from `PubSub`.
- Then the goal is to apply 3 separated transformations from this inputs `PCollection` from `PubSub`
- Each flow applies one of your transformation and sink the result to the destination `Bigquery` table

```
Flow 1 => Map to BQ table 1 => Sink result to BQ table 1 with `BigqueryIO`
Flow 2 => Map to BQ table 2 => Sink result to BQ table 2 with `BigqueryIO`
Flow 3 => Map to BQ table 3 => Sink result to BQ table 3 with `BigqueryIO`
```

In this example I used `STREAMING_INSERT` for ingestion to `Bigquery` tables, but you can adapt and change it if needed in your case.